# Add new screen resolution | BadMatch error |ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, display, display-resolution

I am using ubuntu 20.04 on my desktop.
Sometimes I connect to it by remote desktop from a macbook air m1.

It is very inconvenient that the screen resolution of my ubuntu does not match that of my laptop. My laptop has a resolution of 2560x1600.

So I am trying to add a new screen resolution following this [link](https://bmshamsnahid.medium.com/hand-noadd-a-custom-resolution-in-ubuntu-20-04-gnome-de-7b25e725c8dd)

```
$ cvt 2560 1600
```

gives the following output

```
# 2560x1600 59.99 Hz (CVT 4.10MA) hsync: 99.46 kHz; pclk: 348.50 MHz
Modeline "2560x1600_60.00"  348.50  2560 2760 3032 3504  1600 1603 1609 1658 -hsync +vsync
```

and then run

```
$ `xrandr --newmode "2560x1600_60.00"  348.50  2560 2760 3032 3504  1600 1603 1609 1658 -hsync +vsync`
```

and then run

```
$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "2560x1600_60.00"
```

gives the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  44
```

Comment: This sounds like something that would be configured in the Remote Desktop tool rather than `xrandr` 

Comment: remote desktops can scale, but this results in distortion of the image, because the proportions do not match.